# Google is accidently indexing query string URL parameters and causing my website bandwidth increase

Tags: javascript, php, htaccess, search-engine-indexing, seo

Google is currently indexing query strings URLs of my website. Google has currently indexed almost 112k URLs that all are duplicate version of other URLs causing my website to slow down and negatively effecting my SEO.

The structure of query strings URL is as follows:

```
https://example.com?te=6.18.1346158.4.18.76.huffy+blue+and+white+bike
```

I have contacted search community earlier and they have suggested me to add no index meta tags in my .htacces file with the following code

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /te=/"> Header set X-Robots-Tag noindex </If>
```

Also, I have tried it using `robot.txt` file to block those URLs but no relief.

It's been two weeks since I added this code on my `.htacces` file in my cPanel but still google is indexing those query string parameter URLs.

I am unable to figure out what's the issue please suggest me a possible solution for this as it hitting my website tremendously day by day :(

Comment: Is the `te=` parameter something that your site actually uses?  If not, I'll bet your site is hacked and you need to do a clean install.

Comment: My site is not hacked I've checked it many times and scanned it through my cpanel also.

Comment: What do you use the `te=` params for?

Comment: to block URLs with the strings /?te=

Comment: ... but what do you use the `te` URL parameter for? If this URL param is added erroneously and not used by your application then you would implement a "redirect", otherwise you would implement something like what you are already trying. Are you seeing the `X-Robots-Tag` in the HTTP response for these requests? Presumably you don't have the `<If>` container all on one line as you have posted here? "using `robot.txt` file" - you are missing an `s`; it's `robots.txt`. "my `.htacces` file" - you are missing an `s`; it's `.htaccess`! If you have missed the `s` then it's certainly not going to work.

Comment: Most of the reason that I suspect your site is hacked is that Google wouldn't index the pages if they ware actually duplicate content.  It sounds like the hack is modifying your site for Googlebot and visitors from Google.  You might not even see the hacked content visiting the site yourself.  You don't say how you checked if you site is hacked, but if haven't done so, you need to do a live inspection of your URLs with those parameters from Google Search Console and look at your pages as Googlebot sees them.

Comment: But I have scanned my website to see if my website has an error or virus or either if it is hacked. but I haven't found any culprit 

My website isn't hacked.

Comment: And for the 3rd time... is the `te` param actually used by your site?

Comment: Or, perhaps, to be clearer: Have *you* implemented `te` as a search parameter? Or is this what you are finding in your logs but you have no idea why `te` is being used?

Comment: yes the te parameters is not used by m site and i really don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: Scanning your website is only effective if your scanner has a check for the flavor of malware that is infecting your site. This malware is probably unknown to whatever checker you used.  What checker did you use?  Have you tried my suggestion of using live URL inspection from Google Search Console yet?

Comment: Yes, I have inspected the URLs using the search console inspection tool and it is showing that the URL has no index tag but still the page is showing in index URLs

The bot which is indexing such URLs is google smart phone bot.

Comment: When you inspect the URL, what content do you see?  What is in the screenshot?  What is in the HTML source code that Google shows you it downloaded.

Comment: Why not simply use a sitemap.xml in your site? and vive it to google and check it back in 3 days. After that you need to log the visitor ip,the refferer header and find for something in common. Then you may figured out where this requests came from.

Answer (score 1):

Bots (or anyone) can add query parameters to your URLs, and they will probably still function (unless you've specifically forced it to not work), so there's no purpose in trying to stop that.  Even Facebook uses URL parameters added to URLs occasionally.  To avoid them being indexed though:

1. Make sure the valid URLs you want indexed are in your sitemap, and invalid URLs are not.  If you have no sitemap, it may be a good idea to get one.
2. If you're able, put a canonical tag on EVERYTHING.  That way, Google will recognize the intended URLs.  Examples:

Valid url: `example.com`
Canonical: `example.com`

Invalid url: `example.com?te=6.18.1346158.4.18.76.huffy+blue+and+white+bike`
Canonical: `example.com`

Valid url: `example.com/contact-us.php`
Canonical: `example.com/contact-us.php`

Invalid url: `example.com/contact-us.php?te=blabla`
Canonical: `example.com/contact-us.php`