# Indexed URLs with strange params in my Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console

In my Google Search Console. I have thousands of indexed links to my website but with some strange URL params like this:

```
https://www.example.com/?ve=6.91.11197224.7.17.51.adidas+pants+tiro+17+mens
```

My website has nothing in common with adidas/pants or whatever there is.

How can I get rid of these URLs and how did it happen?

Comment: It looks to me like your site was hacked.  Another person is experiencing a very similar problem with their site right now: [Google is accidently indexing query string URL parameters and causing my website bandwidth increase](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142350/google-is-accidently-indexing-query-string-url-parameters-and-causing-my-website)