# Strange requests by Google for pages that don't exist

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

I've started noticing a large number (over 25,000) of Google Index Bot requests to pages that don't exist and have never existed. I'm certain I don't link to these URLs myself from within my site.

I'm trying to understand what value there would be for someone nefarious to be linking to URLs that don't exist. My first thought is that a competitor is doing this in order for the Google Bot to hit a lot of 404s and possibly demote the site in it's rankings (but that's just a wild guess).

Any insight into what might be happening here? Happy to share URLs if it's useful.

Other relevant points:

- I've had this domain for years, so I don't believe these are links from previous owners

Comment: I'll bet your site was hacked.  We've had a couple of similar questions asked here in the last week.  See [Indexed URLs with strange params in my Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142374/indexed-urls-with-strange-params-in-my-google-search-console) and [Google is accidently indexing query string URL parameters and causing my website bandwidth increase](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142350/google-is-accidently-indexing-query-string-url-parameters-and-causing-my-website)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I’m relatively certain it wasn’t hacked (much more valuable things than SEO link stuffing).

Comment: It would help to know what the URLs look like. In the Google Search Console inspect some if these URLs and see if it tells you who the referrer is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that the problem is in external links. Any new links did you notice in Search Console? In this case Disavow could help. Else theres not much to do.

Second thought: Google tests for errors in dynamically generated URLs. But 25K times? I hardly believe that.

And third: site could be hacked.

Comment: I have a feeling it's external links, but unfortunately GSC doesn't help me figure that out.

Comment: Did you try to check in Ahrefs or similar tool?